# why are two nodes with affectedByGravity = NO attracted to gravity field?

Tags: sprite-kit, gravity, skphysicsbody

I have a 'Moon' which has a gravity field in it and the 'Moon' is set with 'affectedByGravity = NO' and does not get affected by the scene's gravity field.

However I have an 'Asteroid' which also has the 'affectedByGravity = NO' set and it still gets attracted to the 'Moon' but not to the scenes gravity field.

Is this a bug or have I misunderstood how 'affectedByGravity' works?

EDIT: Excerpt from Apple docs

Defining How Forces Affect a Physics Body
affectedByGravity
 Property
**A Boolean value that indicates whether this physics body is affected by the physics world’s gravity and the gravity exerted by any physics fields in the scene**.

Declaration
SWIFT
var affectedByGravity: Bool
Discussion
The physics world’s gravity property defines the gravitational forces applied to volume-based bodies in the scene. The default value is true. This property is ignored on edge-based bodies, which are already unaffected by gravity.

Import Statement
import SpriteKit

Availability
Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

Answer (score 6):

The `affectedByGravity` property is only for the scene's `physicsWorld`, and not for a gravity field. If you want the asteroid to not be affected by the moon, you will have to set it's physicsBody's `fieldBitMask` as 0 (or a value other than that of the gravity field's bitMask).

Read up on the [Adding Physics Fields To Your Scene](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW40) section in Apple's Documentation.

Comment: According to the Apple documentation it is also for gravity exerted by physics fields as well. See updated question,  I should have included this in the original question.  Thanks for the link anyway - I could not find that explanation myself.

Comment: You are right about the documentation. I have never seen affectedByGravity = NO work for SKFieldNode. This is either a bug or a mistake in the docs. A bug report needs to be filed with Apple.